# CLLocation manager delegate not called (swift iOS9)

Tags: swift2, ios9, cllocationmanager

I've worked with CLLocationManager a lot before and I have several other projects where this works just fine with the **EXACT SAME** code... the necessary properties are in the info.Plist as well.

I've tried this both on the simulator and device, both which worked fine in my other projects. If anyone is able to help that would be great because I'm about to lose my mind. Thank you!

Required plist properties

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription </key>
<string>Can we use your location? </string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Can we use your location?</string>
```

The code in the main VC

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let clientKey = ""
let clientSecred = ""
let pushSecret = ""
let fourSquareVersion = ""
let section = ""
var latLong = ""
var currentLat : Double?
var currentLong : Double?
var locationManager : CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {

    if let currentLocation : CLLocation = newLocation {

        currentLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
        currentLong = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude

        print(currentLat)
        print(currentLong)
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that there was a space after NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in the info.plist.